# Iphone: Problem with moving back and forth between two UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let me first describe the context of the problem. I have 2 `UIViewController` call `AdminViewController` and `ButtonReorderViewController`. `AdminViewController` contain 1 button. `ButtonReorderViewController` contains 1 button and 1 picture. Button in `AdminViewController` tie to an event call `goToReorderButton`. The content of `goToReorderButton` are below:

```
ButtonReorderViewController *buttonReorder = [[ButtonReorderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ButtonReorderViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:buttonReorder];  //Add a Navigation Controller to the root view
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
buttonReorder = (ButtonReorderViewController *) navController;
[[buttonReorder view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 470)];
[self.view addSubview:buttonReorder.view];
```

I use `UINavigationController` to allow me to swipe left and right.So I am in `AdminViewController`, and I click on `goToReorderButton`, it load `ButtonReorderViewController`. I am able to swipe left and right (awesome !!!) So I click the button in `ButtonReorderViewController` call `goToAdmin`, simply to go back to the `AdminViewController`

```
-(void) goToAdmin{
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

However, as soon as I go back to `AdminViewController`, I cant click anything at all. The program does not seg fault, it just that I cant click the button at all. if I remove the line `buttonReorder = (ButtonReorderViewController *) navController;` inside `goToReorderButton`, then everything work fine. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I follow you, but I think that you should use the UINavigationController methods to navigate between the view controllers:

The admin view controller should be the root view controller of the navigation controller and then you may push and pop the reorder view controller.

In app delegate (applicationDidFinishLaunching: method):

```
// TODO: Instantiate the adminController

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:adminController];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

In AdminViewController (button touch up inside event handler method):

```
// TODO: Instantiate the buttonReorder

[self.navigationController pushViewController:buttonReorder animated:YES];
```

In ButtonReorderViewController (back button touch up inside event handler method):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Of course, you have to instantiate the view controllers before using them...

Cheers,
Michael.

Comment: I have very similar structure like what u suggest, just a bit more complex. Let say `viewA` is the one I `initWithRootViewController`, since `viewA` will try to display contain from coredata. Let say first view of `viewA`, display 4 object, and there are 8 objects, then swipe right will display the rest of the object. That why `viewA` as UINavigation controller (take advantage of push and pop view). However, if I try to go admin view, then I will not `pushView`, but instead `addSubview`, and then return by `removeFromSuperView`. It work fine, but now I add another component in

Comment: (Please read above first) The new component allow user to reorder object position in view. So in `Admin` view, now I spawn of `viewB`  by `addSubView:viewB`. `viewB` kind of have to same function as `viewA`, so I want to have the ability to `push and pop view`. So I want to make `viewB` a `UINavigationController` like `viewA`. If I click `Return button` then I call `removeFromSuperView` to return back to `Admin`, however, as soon as I come back to `Admin` view, I cant click anything

Comment: As i wrote, none of your view controllers should be a navigation controller. You have ONLY one (in the suggested structure) navigation controller and you just push and pop your (3) view controllers. By the way, the "back" button is built-in in UINavigationItem that is added automatically in the top (the header) - you don't have to implement this button by yourself. Just remove the `[navController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];` line... See some Apple's sample applications. Nav. controller is used almost in each sample application. And always in the same way. Don't try to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Let me rethink my structure. The reason why I have `addSubView` and `push and pop view` is this: Let say that I am in `Admin` view, then I  `push` 3 view on the stack, if I click on the `return` button (which suppose to bring me direct back to the admin view), I have to `pop` 3 times to get back to the three times (keep track of that can be a pain). But if I `addSubView`, I then can just `removeFromSuperView`, to get directly back to `Admin`

Comment: One question though, when we `push and pop view` on or off the stack, is there just one stack that everything go in and out or each viewController has their own stack?

Comment: 1. Why do you need to push 3 view controllers at once? You should push each controller only when you want it to appear.

Comment: 2. You also have `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method if you are in the third controller and want to go back to the first one (Admin).

Comment: 3. Each UINavigationController manages one stack of view controllers. You may have more than one UINavigationController in one application. Perfect example for that is tab controller where each tab contains separate navigation controller...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the app crashed on that line you pointed out. Does the debug console output anything when it crashes?

Looks like the line `buttonReorder = (ButtonReorderViewController *) navController;` is failing on the cast. Are you sure `ButtonReorderViewController` extends `UINavigationController`? If not, then you can't cast it like that.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but i think you can use PusViewController method of NavigationController  to do your job.